# Zoom a rendered PDF in VirtualCanvasControl

Tags: pdf, win-universal-app, rendering, zooming

I am rendring a PDF Page to a CanvasBitmap and draw this Image on a VirtualCanvasControl. But whenever I zoom in the picture gets pixelated.
I tried to render just the part that is visible but that does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  Grid.Row="0" 
                  Name="PdfScrollViewer" 
                  ZoomMode="Enabled"
                  MaxZoomFactor="4"
                  MinZoomFactor="0.8"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False">
        <canvas:CanvasVirtualControl x:Name="PageRenderCanvas" RegionsInvalidated="PageRenderCanvas_OnRegionsInvalidated"
               />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

The RegionsInvalidated EventHandler:

```
private async void PageRenderCanvas_OnRegionsInvalidated(CanvasVirtualControl sender,
        CanvasRegionsInvalidatedEventArgs args)
    {
        PdfPageRenderOptions options = new PdfPageRenderOptions();
        options.DestinationWidth = (uint) (PdfScrollViewer.ActualWidth*PdfScrollViewer.ZoomFactor);
        options.DestinationHeight = (uint) (PdfScrollViewer.ActualHeight*PdfScrollViewer.ZoomFactor);
        options.SourceRect = args.VisibleRegion;

        var output = new MemoryStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
        await page.RenderToStreamAsync(output, options); // page is the PDFPage

        var image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(PageRenderCanvas, output);

        using (var ds = sender.CreateDrawingSession(args.InvalidatedRegions[0]))
        {
            ds.DrawImage(image, args.VisibleRegion);

            ds.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is pixelated because you are performing the zoom on the rendered bitmap.
Since there is not much documentation on VirtualCanvasControl and RegionsInvalidated event I recommend to perform the rendering every time the zoom changes and just display the rendered image in the drawing event. 
However this approach will generate memory problems at large zoom levels. Considering 96dpi for 100%, a letter page will be 816*1056 pixels and will take about 3MB. At 500% zoom the image will be 4080*5280 pixels and will take about 75MB.

Comment: Yeah I already aborted this aproach, it takes to much memory on Phones. I'm trying to render only the visible part, but it is also blurry.